# changing the upload max size on lamp

Tags: php, lamp, max-size

I'm using lamp on linux and I want to change the upload maxi size but I can't find php.ini, any lead to help me ? I tried find php.ini on the terminal but it didn't find anything

Comment: /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini?

Comment: in /etc/php5 I only have 3 folders: conf.d, embed and mods-available

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to find loaded `php.ini` by running the following command in your terminal:

```
php -i | grep "Loaded Configuration File"
```

Or if you like, create a file called `phpinfo.php` and place the following content:

```
<?php phpinfo();
```

then navigate to `http://localhost/phpinfo.php` in your browser (assuming you are running this in your localhost) and find the "Loaded Configuration File" around the top section of the page.